# Is my application of Burnside's Lemma correct in this combinatorial problem?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

For a course in Combinatorics (I know very little group theory unfortunately), we've been tasked to use Burnside's Lemma on the following problem:

Suppose you write a 5-digit number on a piece of paper (numbers smaller than 10,000 have zeros added in front of them). If you hold the paper upside down, the numbers 0,1,6,8,9 are read as 0,1,9,8,6 respectively. We identify the numbers that are readable both ways (e.g. 89166 and 99168).

The question is of course: how many different numbers are there really?

The problem I have with this exercise is that my calculation differs wildly from that of my fellow students (who find about 50800 different numbers), so I'd like to know what is (possibly) wrong with my calculation, and in the process learn to understand Burnside's Lemma better.

My calculation is as follows:

Out of the 10000 possible numbers, only those numbers wich are legible upside down are of interest to us for now $|S| = 5^5 = 3125$. The permutationgroup consists of the identity, and the 'holding the paper upside down'-permutation.

For the identity, every element is invariant, so we have 3125 elements.

For the other permutation, an element is invariant if it is the same when it is read upside down, so that gives $5^2 \cdot 3 = 75$ possibilities.

Applying Burnside's Lemma we get $\frac{3125 + 75}{2} = 1600$ unique elements. This seems quite logical to me: about half of the 3125 numbers are actually counted double, however 75 are not, so that gives $\frac{3125 - 75}{2} + 75$ unique numbers.

Finalizing, there are 10000 numbers, subtracting the 3125 numbers that can be read upside down, and adding the unique ones gives 98475 actually unique numbers.

Evidently, my answer is different, however I'm interested to know what is actually correct. Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Your calculation looks correct. I was wondering how other students got $50800$, and the best I could do was observe $50800=\frac{100000+1600}{2}$. Just in case, would it be possible to quote the original exercise verbatim, or is it in a different language?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly their calculation. They're a bright lot though, and way more intelligent than I am, so perhaps I read the exercise wrong, haha. The assignment is written in Dutch, which I am guessing you don't speak ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Burnside I get the following result. By inspection we have the following cycle index: 
$$\frac{1}{2}(a_1^5 + a_1 a_2^2).$$
We need to compute the number of digit sequences fixed by these two permutations, the identity and the flip. Furthermore the flip exchanges sixes and nines at the same time as it permutes slots.

The identity fixes all $10^5$ digit sequences. For the flip according to Burnside we must have constant values on the cycles taking into account that a six and a nine placed on a two-cycle are also constant because the flip simultaneously exchanges those digits. We cannot have a six or a nine on the one-cycle because they wouldn't be constant on that cycle. This gives the following four possibilities:
$$8\times 8\times 8 + 8 \times 8\times 2 + 8\times 2\times 8 + 8\times 2\times 2.$$
The first factor in these four products corresponds to the choice for the one-cycle and the next two to the choices for the two two-cycles. These are eight or two, depending on whether we choose a digit that is not six nor nine, or we choose either six and nine or nine and six.

Burnside now yields
$$\frac{1}{2}
\left(10^5 + 8\times 8\times 8 + 8 \times 8\times 2 + 
8\times 2\times 8 + 8\times 2\times 2\right) = 50400.$$

The following code snippet was used to verify the above calculation.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

MAIN: {
    my %seen;

    for(my $n=0; $n<10**5; $n++){
        my $m = sprintf "%05d", $n;
        my $rev = reverse $m;

        $rev =~ s/6/x/g;
        $rev =~ s/9/y/g;

        $rev =~ s/x/9/g;
        $rev =~ s/y/6/g;

        my @l = sort { $a <=> $b } ($m, $rev);
        $seen{$l[0] . "-" . $l[1]} = 1;
    }

    print scalar(keys %seen);
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: What cycles are you referring to?

Comment: This choice of term comes from the Polya Enumeration Theorem, where the permutations are factored into cycles to compute the cycle index. The cardinality of the set of five-digit strings being fixed by a particular permutation of the two possible permutations is computed observing that they must be constant on the cycles of that permutation. Signing off for the day.

Comment: When you explain the factor $8\times8\times8$ you mention one $1$-cycle and two $2$-cycles, and insinuate the entries of the cycles are single digits. But the flip permutation has $1$-cycles that look like $(96196)$ and $2$-cycles that look like $(89166~99168)$; the entries are $5$-digit numbers, and there are going to be a buttload of these cycles (more than just three). Also, as a test to determine what you're thinking here, answer this: if you flip, say, $23457$, what five-digit number do you get? Finally, you don't offer any response to the OP's reasoning.

Comment: I'm sorry, while I do not doubt the validity of your claims, this is way above my level of understanding. I mentioned before that my knowledge of abstract algebra is very limited, haha. I can accept your answer, but since our answers differ, I'd first like to ask you to point (in layman's terms) where I went wrong. This is fair, no?

Comment: The problem statement is somewhat ambiguous which is why your fellow students might easily have obtained a different answer. The group seems right. But the identity fixes all digit strings i.e. $10^5$ and not only $5^5.$ For the flip it is correct that we need the count of the strings that it leaves invariant. So that means there cannot be a six or a nine at the center, as these are never left fixed. Now just look at the pair of squares at the beginning and at the end and the pair adjacent to them. These either need to be identical or consist of a six and a nine (8 and 2 possibilities).

Comment: The number of upside-down-readable flip-invariant five-digit numbers should be $5\cdot 5\cdot3=75$ exactly as the OP describes (the first two fives count the ways of putting $0,1,6,8,9$ into the first two digits, which thereby determines the last two digits, and the three counts the ways of putting $0,1,8$ in the middle digit). The number of five-digit numbers that are upside-down-unreadable is given by $10^5-5^5=96875$. If you assume the flip acts trivially on upside-down-unreadable numbers, then there are $75+96875$ flip-invariant five-digit numbers.

Comment: *These either need to be identical or consist of a six and a nine (8 and 2 possibilities).* I have no idea where you are getting these $8$s and $2$s from.

Comment: Thank you. I completely misunderstood the problem. Good to know that you were able to help the OP and verify the solution.